# Delphi 10.3.3 FireDAC FDConnection.GetTableNames Interbase

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to put some FireDAC orders to a unit. I realized an FDConnection with a create order.
My problem: I always get a failure using GetTableNames.
See procedure FD_DBTabellen_holen.

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot
Martin

```
interface

type

    TSW_FDDataBase = class
        constructor Init;
        destructor  Done;

        private
      oFDConnection   : TFDConnection;
      //oFDTransaction  : TFDTransaction;
            oDbName         :   TFileName;
      oDBDriverID     : String;
      oTableNames     : TStringList;
        public

  end;
var
  oFD_DB : TSW_FDDataBase;

  procedure FD_DBTabellen_holen;

And here is the trouble maker:

procedure FD_DBTabellen_holen;
begin
  oFD_DB.oFDConnection.GetTableNames('', '', '', oFD_DB.oTableNames,
    [osMy, osOther], [tkTable], true);
end;
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting with your question

Comment: Has oTableNames been initialized?

Comment: Although perfectly syntaxically correct, it is probably a bad idea to name contructor 'Init' and destructor 'Done'.

Answer (score 0):

@Todd: thanks for answering very soon. I got 2 different errors starting with or without the debugger.
Without debugger: Runtime error 216 at 00408216
With debugger: An error occured in the project FD.exe reading from address 0x004739b7, read of address 0014

@fpiette:

TSW_FDDataBase = class
privat
oTableNames     : TStringList;
public

end;

var oFD_DB : TSW_FDDataBase;

initialization
oFD_DB := TSW_FDDataBase.Create;
oFD_DB.Init;
end.